# WebStorm auto-reformatting JS code options: newline after class declaration - before '{'?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, code-formatting

I found many nice options for auto-reformatting code in WebStorm (Settings->Editor->Code Style-> JavaScript), but how can I change this newline-after-class-declaration formatting:

```
export class A{
    constructor( something )
    {
    ....
```

to this:

```
export class A
{
    constructor( something )
    {
    ....
```

?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option to do that in WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such option currently, please vote for [WEB-20152](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20152).